# Download Manager with priority (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, download

I'm doing a little download manager within my app. I was using

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadpool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,210, (int) 210, TimeUnit.SECONDS,new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(210), new mThreadFactory());
```

and calling the following method for order the downloads:

```
threadpool.execute( new DownloadRunnable(url) );
```

Recently I changed a little my app and now I need to distinguish two kinds of downloads: Foreground Downloads (for elements that need to be shown to the user asap) and Background Downloads for saving a Internet resource at the disk for example.

I want some kind of pool executor always when picking the new element for download priorize Foreground downloads if exists and else download a background resource.

Can someone guide me with that solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PriorityBlockingQueue instead of your ArrayBlockingQueue and give the foreground downloads a higher priority.